# DataGrid Gripper style

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

i want to style the row header gripper style to be like the column header style
how to do that?

i want the headers to look like this:

```
<Style x:Key="dataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="34"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource clalBlueGlossyGradientEffect}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1, 0, 0, 0" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />        
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>        
    </Style>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        BorderBrush="{Binding VerticalGridLinesBrush, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}}}"
                        Cursor="SizeWE"/>